# Setting up a Quick Build that works

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, compiling, workflow

everyone! I'm pretty new to LaTex and I'm trying to get a grasp of it to use it on my thesis.
I'm trying to setup a nice workflow so I won't get stuck every couple minutes before I start actually writing the whole thing down. I'm using TexMaker 5.0.2 and BiblaTex on MacOs High Sierra.
The workflow that I found to work (with the help of a more experienced friend) is:
Select for references.bib file > Run the "1. Biber" command > Select the main.tex file > Run the quick build (which is now default only: LatexToPdf + View PDF)
I will say this may be dumb to do, but I am a newbie after all :)

Could anyone help me set up a custom Quick Build to do this in just one click?

P.S. I tried the option LatexToPdf + Bib(la)Tex + LatexToPdf (x2) + View PDF but it doesn't seem to work for me.. And I don't fully understand what's he's trying to do...

Thanks all :)

Comment: I assume you saw https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864 and followed the instructions for your editor there?

Comment: As explained in my link you can set up TeXmaker in a way that Quick build always triggers Biber for all documents. If you then select `LatexToPdf + Bib(la)Tex + LatexToPdf (x2) + View PDF` everything should be good. Of course you could also use more sophisticated tools like `latexmk` (determines automatically which commands need to be run) and `arara` (lets you set up complex rules to decide what to run).

Comment: Also: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I wouldn't use such a quick build which calls always all tools. It will only slow down the compilation. Normally when writing you need only one pdflatex run, and a full cycle only every hour or so.

Comment: @moewe That's what is was looking for. I can't manage to find the biber directory on my laptop though..

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I get citations undefined every time I compile if I don't do this routine though, don't I? Do you suggest I let it as it is and just run the biber command time to time?

Comment: It should be in the same directory as all your other TeX-related binaries (`pdflatex` etc.), so you should be able to copy the path from the other fields. Maybe it is enough to just type `biber` if it is in your system path.

Comment: @moewe I managed via terminal, thanks! :) I'll give it a go to see how it works as to now

Comment: If you don't clean up after each compilation run (i.e. remove the temporary `.aux`, `.bbl`, `.bcf` files) it is not necessary to run Biber each time LaTeX is run. You only need to run Biber if the contents of your `.bib` file changed or if something in your `.tex` file changed so significantly that the bibliography is affected (you change the style or other bibliography settings, or you change the order in which you cite your sources, ...). Usually changes that require a Biber run happen less often that LaTeX-only changes and for many things that require a Biber re-run you get a warning.

Comment: @moewe Thanks a lot! Now I at least understand what I'm doing when! Awesome support. You guys are great! Have a great day :)

Comment: Can we close this as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864?

Comment: @moewe yes, please :)